# Running Jasmine Unit Test within Visual Studio via TFS

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs, jasmine

Hello I got a question regarding implementing Jasmine unit tests within a specific build of TFS. I found this [Tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx) which  explains exactly what I want.

But I do not want to use this because I do not want to check in phantomjs.exe, which is a file of +/- 46 MB, so what could I do next?

Does anyone of you know if there is a tutorial available on the web regarding installing it (instead on the TFS) directly on the build server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible to reference Chutzpah as a NuGet package:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah

With that package referenced (and Visual Studio 2013 update 2 or later), the tests will be executed during the build. You will need to perform the other steps of adjusting the `.runsettings` and the test assembly specification to include your test files `...;*.test.js`

Comment: But If I do that, does Chutzpah not include the phantomjs.exe to the TFS? Is a reference via NuGet not the same as checking in the files?

Comment: If you do not check in the packages folder, TFS will automatically restore the package when building the application.

Comment: NuGet will automatically cache the packages it downloads, so it should not have to do that every time you run our build: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx

Comment: I will give it a try! :) Thanks!